# RouterModule.forRoot() called twice. Lazy loaded modules should use RouterModule.forChild() instead

Tags: angular, module, lazy-evaluation, angular-router

I m importing AppModule in Lazy loaded module which is creating error : Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: RouterModule.forRoot() called twice. Lazy loaded modules should use RouterModule.forChild() instead.

**app module**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { NgClockPickerLibModule } from 'ng-clock-picker-lib';
import { SharedDataService } from './services/shared-data.service';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,  
    NgClockPickerLibModule,
    ...
  ],
  providers: [
    SharedDataService,
    ...
  ],
  exports: [
    NgClockPickerLibModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app routing module**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'journalling', loadChildren: './Journalling/modules/journalling.module#JournallingModule' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  declarations: [

  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**journalling module**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { JournallingRoutingModule } from './journalling-routing.module';
import { AppModule } from 'src/app/app.module';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    JournallingRoutingModule,
    AppModule
  ],
  declarations: [ 
  ],
  providers: [
  ]
})
export class JournallingModule { }
```

**journalling routing module**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [  
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class JournallingRoutingModule { }
```

[Error RouterModule.forRoot() called twice. Lazy loaded module should use forChild() instead.][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMDry.png

Answer (score 3):

**journalling module**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { JournallingRoutingModule } from './journalling-routing.module';
import { AppModule } from 'src/app/app.module'; <--- remove this import

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    JournallingRoutingModule,
    AppModule // <--- remove this import
  ],
  declarations: [ 
  ],
  providers: [
  ]
})
export class JournallingModule { }
```

The problem is that you're importing the AppModule in your JournallingModule which causes RouterModule.forRoot() to be called twice. AppModule is your root module and should not be imported in child modules.

Comment: I need to import AppModule bcz of NgClockPickerLibModule which is exported in AppModule, to use this module in JournallingModule i imported AppModule in JournallingModule. And NgClock-Module cant be directly imported in JournalligModule bcz its importing BrowserAnimationsModule internally and if i do so i get an error : "browsermodule has already been loaded" . So I imported NgClock-Module in AppModule along with BrowserModule and export this NgClock-Module from AppModule and import AppModule in JournallingModule to access NgClock-Module in JournallingModule.

Comment: You can remove BrowserModule from imports in app.module.ts, in addition to what I've put in my answer, since BrowserAnimationsModule imports BrowserModule.

Comment: if i remove AppModule from JournallingModule and BrowserModule from AppModule then i get this error : Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'ngClass' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.

Comment: Also if i just dont import AppModule in JournallingModule then NgClockPickerLibModule is not accessible to components inside JournallingModule